# Get drawables that make up an EditText?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the drawable resources that make up an EditText?

Specifically I'd like to know the drawables that make up the focused and non focused states.

I thought the EditText background was a StateListDrawable, then I could grab out the selected resources, but when examining, it is a "TintDrawableWrapper":

```
EditText et = ...;
Log.v(TAG, "Background: " + et.getBackground());

// prints:
android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintDrawableWrapper
```

so there's not much documentation on that class, or if it's even the same on all platforms.

Separately I was looking at other posts if the drawables had names, like:

```
@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal
```

but these look like old styles assets that don't match.

Any ideas on how I could get those assets? I've considered creating an off-screen EditText, then drawing it to a bitmap, but to get the focused drawable state, I would have to have the EditText request focus, which would probably pop the keyboard up etc and cause all kinds of problems.

Thanks

Comment: where have you looked for them? what platform?

Comment: I just assigned those explicit resource names to a view in my app, then ran it on my 4.4.4 device. The assets look like gingerbread EditText assets.

Comment: Please try to search for it in platforms/android-21/res/ folder at your android sdk location. What's there?

Comment: Yeah I see it in there, looks like what I see in the app - a 9 patch that contains a white box with rounded corners. Not sure what this one is even used for, haven't seen it on 4.x ever?